# How can I send data to zipkin from kafka in java?

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, zipkin

I hope you can help me. Let's use for example this very simple code

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class ms_example1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input").to("streams-pipe-output");


        final Topology topology = builder.build();

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Like you can see this microservice only forwards messages from one kafka-topic to another. I also want to send this data to zipkin to see the duration of the messages or something like that.

Maybe I've seen the solution and don't get it but I realy have looked for a solution but didn't find one. You are my last hope. I have seen the brave api but I don't realy understand how to use it for kafka. I

Comment: I guess you could study this example: https://github.com/jeqo/talk-kafka-zipkin

Comment: A related article is https://www.confluent.io/blog/importance-of-distributed-tracing-for-apache-kafka-based-applications, which explains how to use Kafka's interceptor API to integrate Kafka, Kafka Connect, Kafka Streams, KSQL with Zipkin for distributed tracing. This might be an alternative to your idea of writing directly from your Java application to Zipkin.